# openvpn - unable to do ssh using openVPN to another EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, openvpn, aws-vpc-peering

**Architecture( within SAME ACCOUNT)-**

1. **OpenVPN** is present in **VPC A (10.41.0.0/16)** and was configured using AWS marketplace in region **ap-south-1**.
2. Another instance **"test"** is in **VPC B (10.40.0.0/16)** in a different region **ca-central-1**
3. There is a **VPC peering** between VPC A to VPC B and vice versa

**Current Situation**

1. I am able to ssh into OpenVPN instance and telnet to "test" at 22 is working which indicates that peering is working as expected

**Problem**

1. When I connect to the OpenVPN server and then try to do an ssh to "test" EC2 instance in VPC B, I am getting a timeout error at port 22.

**Things I have tried so far**

1. Check telnet at 22 from VPC A to VPC B
2. Verify NACLs, Route tables, security Groups for port 22 in both the VPC ranges

I am unable to figure out the issue, If somebody has worked on this and could help me debug this issue would be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To facilitate your access to a specific server through OpenVPN, please follow the steps outlined below:

- Log in to the OpenVPN Access Server web console.
- Navigate to User Management > User Permissions.
- Click on "More Settings" for the relevant VPN user.
- Add the desired server IP address under Access Control.
- Save the changes.

Following these steps, you should be able to connect to the server seamlessly through OpenVPN.

Thanks.